# i18next jquery help migrating to i18next jquery v3.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18next

Good day all,

i need a little bit of help migrating from i18next jquery 1.11.1 to version 3.0.0
currently this is my setup

```
<!-- Core JS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/i18next.min.js"></script> (v1.11.1)

$(function(){
    // i18next Configuration
    // -------------------------
    var namespaces = ["nav" ,"common" ];
    var options = {
            ns: {
                namespaces: namespaces,
                defaultNs: namespaces[0]
            },
            resGetPath: '../assets/locales/__ns__/__lng__.json',
            debug: false,
            load: 'unspecific',
            detectLngQS: 'lang',
            fallbackLng : 'en',
            cookieName: 'applang',
            //cookieExpirationTime : ,
            useLocalStorage: false,
            cookieDomain: '*.mydomain.com',
            useCookie: true,
            lngWhitelist: ['en','es', 'de', 'fr']
        };
    i18n.init(options ,function (err,t) {
        $('body').i18n(); // Init 18n

    });
})
```

and when i want to load additional namespace i do this

```
var namespaces = ["newFile"];
i18n.loadNamespaces(namespaces, function (err, t) {
        // init i18n
        $('body').i18n();
   .............. other stuff in here
})
```

but when i try to use the latest i18next v3 with the jquery-i18next (https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next) keeping the same logic i get errors on the loadNamespaces function (Uncaught TypeError: namespaces.forEach is not a function), below is the new setup

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/3.0.0/i18next.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-i18next/0.0.2/i18next-jquery.min.js" ></script>

i18next
  .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
  .init({
      lng: 'de',
      backend: {
          loadPath: '../assets/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
      }
    }, function(err, t) {
      jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
      $('.body').localize();

  });

  var namespaces = ["newFile"];
  i18n.loadNamespaces(namespaces, function (err, t) {
        // init i18n
        $('body').localize();
   .............. other stuff in here
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested here is my solution

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/core/libraries/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins/internationalization/i18next.min-v3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins/internationalization/jquery-i18next.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins/internationalization/i18nextXHRBackend.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins/internationalization/i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins/internationalization/i18nextLocalStorageCache.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/plugins/internationalization/i18nextIntervalPluralPostProcessor.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
    // i18next Configuration
    // -------------------------
var namespaces = ["nameSpace1" ,"NameSpace2" ],
    cacheOptions = {
        // turn on or off
        enabled: true, // prefix for stored languages
        prefix: 'i18next_res_',
        expirationTime: 1*24*60*60*1000 // expiration
    },
    lngDetectionOption = {
        //order and from where user language should be detected
        order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag'],
        //keys or params to lookup language from
        lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
        lookupCookie: 'i18next',
        lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLocalStorage',
        //cache user language on
        caches: ['localStorage','cookie'],
        // optional expire and domain for set cookie
        cookieMinutes: 365*24*60, // 1 year
        cookieDomain: 'myDomain',
        // optional htmlTag with lang attribute, the default is:
        htmlTag: document.documentElement
    },
    i18nextoptions = {
        compatibilityJSON: 'v2',
        debug: true,
        whitelist : ['en','es', 'de', 'fr'],
        ns: namespaces,
        load: 'unspecific',
        fallbackLng : 'en',
        detection: lngDetectionOption,
        backend: {loadPath: '../assets/locales/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json'},
        //cache : cacheOptions
    };

i18next
    .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
    .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
    .use(Cache)
    .use(i18nextIntervalPluralPostProcessor)
    .init(i18nextoptions, function (err, t) {
        var options = $().jqueryI18nextOptions;
        //init jquery-i18next
        jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $,options);

        $('body').i18n(); // Init 18n

    })
})
```

Comment: There is also a newer guide here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3